# How to make a list in maple

Tags: maple

I need to do some computations with maple which I don't know how to do it. So I thought I can ask you.

I am going to pick a simple function, as simple as possible. let's take $f(x,y):=x^2+y^2$. I want to **make a list** with maple to give me a list of numbers producing with $f(x,y)$ for integral value $x=1...5$, and $y=1...5$, in other word a list consists of $f(1,1), f(1,2), f(1,3),..., f(5,5)$.

Of course my function and the range is much more complicate, so I just took this particular function just to be more precise.

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=rtable

Comment: @J.M. I'm not quite sure why this is considered off-topic. Can you illuminate me?

Comment: @Theo: I don't know either, so I didn't vote to close on this one. OTOH, the old version of myself would have said "RTFM" for this question, but I'm *really* trying to be a nice guy these days...

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
> f := (x,y) -> x^2 + y^2;
```

$$ f := (x,y) \to x^2 + y^2 $$

```
> M := Matrix(5, 5, f);
```

$$ M := \begin{bmatrix}
 2 &   5 &  10 &  17 &  26 \\
 5 &   8 &  13 &  20 &  29 \\
10 &  13 &  18 &  25 &  34 \\
17 &  20 &  25 &  32 &  41 \\
26 &  29 &  34 &  41 &  50
\end{bmatrix}$$

```
> ListTools:-Flatten( convert(M, listlist) );
```

$$[2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 5, 8, 13, 20, 29, 10, 13, 18, 25, 34, 17, 20, 25, 32, 41, 26, 29, 34, 41, 50]$$